# Basic Combinatorics and total possibilities

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

Question:
There are 3 different pants, 4 different shirts and 5 different sunglasses. How many outfits can you prepare for a morning and afternoon outing if you have to have a different article of clothing for each outing (No using the same piece twice)

Work:

FCP
Morning outing: 3 * 4 * 5=60
Afternoon outing: 2 * 3 * 4=24
Total = Morning * Afternoon = 1440

Combinations:
Choose 1 outfit to prepare: 2C1
Choose 1 article of each pant, shirt, sunglasses:3C1 * 4C1 * 5C1
Choose the other outfit to prepare: 1C1
Choose 1 article of remaining pant, shirt, sunglasses: 2C1 * 3C1 * 4C1
Total= 2 * 1440

Combinations 2nd method:
Choose 2 outfits to prepare: 2C2
Choose 2 articles of each pant, shirt, sunglasses: 3C2 * 4C2 * 5C2
Total: 180

All of these *seem* like they make sense conversationally but all have different answers. How should I go about this one logically?

Comment: In "Combinations", why two outfits to prepare? You are saying that in the morning you will have two outfits to choose from, and you are left with one, but you only have one option.

Comment: Are you referring to the 2c1?  I have that since I am not distinguishing between afternoon and morning and just leaving it as 2 outfits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first one is correct. There are $1440$ ways to pick the outfits.

In combinations, you're double counting by a factor of $2$. The same choice of outfits is counted twice, once when you choose the morning outfit first, then the evening outfit, and it is also counted separately when you choose the evening outfit first.

In the second combinations method, you have chosen which pant, shirt, and sunglasses you are going to where throughout the day. Now, multiply $180$ by the number of ways to choose *which* pant, which shirt, and which sunglasses you will where in the morning. The rest will be worn in the evening.

Thus, the problem is reduced to finding the number of ways you can choose an outfit out of $2$ pants, $2$ shirts and $2$ sunglasses. The number of choices for each item is $2$.

So there are a total of $2\times 2\times 2=8$ ways to choose what you will where in the morning after choosing for the whole day.

Thus, the answer will come to $180\times 8=1440,$ which is indeed what you got by the first method.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response especially for combinations 2nd method. I have a follow up question if you could help me with that. What in the question makes order necessary? I feel like this situation we could prepare the afternoon outfit before morning outfit so for the FCP method we would multiply by 2? What are your thoughts on that? Poorly worded question but accurate mathematically if order doesn’t matter?

Comment: @user1278599 The question asks for how many outfits you can pick, so whether you choose the morning outfit first or the evening outfit, the final choice of outfits prepared would be the same, so it should be counted only once. Here by "order" I was talking about the order in which you choose your outfit. While this order is not important, you do have to consider which outfit will be worn in the morning and which in the evening.

Comment: Thanks that make it quite clear!